# Scrapy: ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True gives an error

Tags: python, scrapy

When setting ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True in scrapy settings I get the following error: 
    `TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got list`.

I've tried multiple websites to see if it was an issue with the robots.txt file, but i get the same error for all websites.  Even for google 
    `scrapy shell https://www.google.com/ --set="ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True"`

```
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got list
```

How can I respect robots.txt and crawl using scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue.  When USER_AGENT is set I get the error.  If no USER_AGENT is set then ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True works without error.

Comment: Consider opening a feature request in https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/ to ask for a better error message in this scenario.